# How to detect drag velocity in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to detect drag velocity in flutter ?
I want to draw on screen in flutter using custom paint, when the velocity is less the stroke width should be less, but when the drag velocity is high the stroke width should be greater.

```
GestureDetector(
                  onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject();
                        Offset _localPosition =
                            object.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
                        _points = List.from(_points)..add(_localPosition);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => {
                    _deletedPoints.clear(),
                    _points.add(null),
                    // _listPoints.add(_points),
                    // _listPoints = List.from(_listPoints)..add(_points),
                  },
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: Draw(points: _points),
                    size: Size.infinite,
                  ),
                ),
```

The custom draw widget that extends customPainter

```
class Draw extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> points;
  // List<List<Offset>> points;
  Draw({this.points});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = brushColor
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = brushWidth;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], paint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Draw oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.points != points;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

velocity is how much the position changed in a given time.

for this purpose you have the `details.delta.distance` in the `onPanUpdate` callback, which returns a double indicating how much the pointer has moved since last update, the bigger it is, the larger the velocity.

in your case, you can change the stroke width based on the distance traveled.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used any of these myself but you could look into
DragUpdateDetails. `details` in `onPanUpdate` has an Offset object called `delta`. Which are coordinates which update every time `onPanUpdate` is called.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/DragUpdateDetails-class.html

There's also a class called `VelocityTracker`

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/VelocityTracker-class.html

Hope this helps you a bit

Answer (score 0):

[Update] a practical example

```dart
late final Ticker _velocityTicker;
final List<int> _velocityRecs = List.filled(6, 0, growable: true);
double _rec = 0;
get _deltaSum {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < _velocityRecs.length; i++) {
    sum += (_velocityRecs[i] - _velocityRecs[i - 1]).abs();
  }
  return sum;
}

/// in initState()
_velocityTicker = Ticker((duration) {
  _velocityRecs.removeAt(0);
  // add whatever values you want to track
  _velocityRecs.add(_currentIndex);
  // You get a 'velocity' here, do something you want
  if (_deltaSum > 2) {
    // _offsetYController.forward();
  } else if (_deltaSum < 1) {
    // _offsetYController.reverse();
  }
});

/// then .start()/.stop() the ticker in your event callback
/// Since each ticker has a similar time interval, 
/// for Simplicity, I did not use duration here, 
/// if you need a more accurate calculation value, 
/// you may need to use it
```

In short, You can't.

Although details.delta and VelocityTracker are mentioned above, neither of them technically has access to the user's PointerEvent velocity,

For example, if the user drags the slider and stops, but the finger does not leave the screen, the velocity should be about 0, but this state can't be captured in flutter.

velocityTracker doesn't help

If you want to implement it yourself, one idea is to create a Timer/Ticker, record the last value and put it into a list, then set it to zero, and each time you want get, the sum of the whole list will be averaged to get the velocity, you need to be careful to determine how much the length of your List is appropriate